# Displaying and updating pinned objects in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, local-datastore

I'm trying to integrate the Parse local datastore into my app as a local cache.

I want to display a list of items that will remain the same for most of the time but could be added to or removed from occasionally.

These changes are managed on the Parse.com website (for now).

What I would like to be able to do is to display the locally pinned objects and at the same time fetch any changes from online and then update the displayed items to reflect that.

From what I have read the local query and the online query are mutually exclusive.

So I think the only way to do this is to do something like...

1. Create a local datastore query to get all the items and display them.
2. Start a query the connects to Parse.com and downloads the (potentially) updated items and pin any changes.
3. Run another local datastore query to get an updated list of items and reload the tableview (or whatever) is displaying them.

Am I correct in my assumption? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is my understanding as well. I'm not even sure you can just "re-pin" objects without unpinning them first.... I'm hoping for a future "refreshAllPinnedObjectsFromRemote" or something.

Comment: if you enable local datastore and just run the query as normal, test for yourself what happens. So do this, run the query, without doing anything before hand, just run the query raw, then populate the tableview. THEN put your iphone in airplane mode, and restart the app. navigate away from the tableview then back to the view and you should see that the view is still poulated with data. Enabling local datastore very much takes care of the heavy lifting for you and its a rate circumstance that it doesn't do what you want to where you need to pull new data, unless you know you need new data.

Comment: @Larcerax I will give this a try but from what I read in the documentation you have to explicitly set the query as `fromLocalDatastore` and then it won't touch the network. Similarly if a  query is not for the network it won't touch the local datastore. To use the local datastore you first need to pin items and then you can make a local query to retrieve them without touching the network.

Comment: yeah, I know what you mean, but first try just raw without, and then if this doesn't cut it then move to local calls. I just never use the local calls, I don't like them and they are not that useful in the cases where I need presistence, but mainly because the persistence seems to maintain itself quite well without the local calls, but I do know persistence is happening, the documents folder does fill up with parse data and if you look at the parse SDK open source, you'll see that it queries local, then network when eanblelocaldatastore is checked.

Comment: @vacawama thanks very much. I was able to get around it another way. But I'll def think about that for the next time :D